# Error: skin 'WVGA800' does not exist

Tags: android, command-line

These are my available android targets (by running the following in the command prompt `android list targets`):

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-9"
     Name: Android 2.3.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 9
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi
----------
id: 2 or "android-10"
     Name: Android 2.3.3
     Type: Platform
     API level: 10
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi, default/x86
----------
id: 3 or "android-11"
     Name: Android 3.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 11
     Revision: 2
     Skins: WXGA (default)
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi
----------
id: 4 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 4
     Skins: 
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86
----------
id: 5 or "android-21"
     Name: Android 5.0.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 21
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearSquare
 Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, android-wear/armeabi-v7a, android-wear/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64
----------
id: 6 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:9"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 2
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 2.3.1 (API level 9)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi
----------
id: 7 or "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
     Name: Glass Development Kit Preview
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 11
     Description: Preview of the Glass Development Kit
     Based on Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
     Libraries:
      * com.google.android.glass (gdk.jar)
          APIs for Glass Development Kit Preview
     Skins: 
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

Now I am trying to make one with target id `4` as follows:

```
android create avd --name device2 --target 4 --abi default/x86
```

...and I get an output as follows:

```
Error: Skin 'WVGA800' does not exist.
Error: AVD not created.
```

How to install that skin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was with the sdk package manager I had obtained. It wasn't downloaded and installed as is done traditionally. I got it from a network share in my organization.

To fix this, I had to delete android-19 stuff (android 4.4.2) and re-install it via the SDK manager.